# How can I reference an existing method in Raku?

Tags: function, reference, raku, function-reference

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Functions_are_first-class_objects), you can reference an existing function by prepending the `&` sigil:

```
&say       # reference to the `say` function
&infix:<+> # reference to the infix `+` operator
```

How do I do this for methods?

Answer (score 6):

This [article](https://vrurg.github.io/2023/07/04/did-you-know-that)'s author explains there are a few possibilities to get hold of a method object, however the most relevant one here is to use the MOP method [`.^lookup`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lookup):

```
say Array.^lookup('push').raku

#`«
proto method push ($: |) {*}
»
```

For example to get all the candidates's signatures for `Array`'s `push` method you'd do:

```
.say for Array.^lookup('push').candidates.map(*.signature);

#`«
(Any:U \SELF: |values)
(Array:D: Slip \value, *%_ --> Array:D)
(Array:D: \value, *%_ --> Array:D)
(Array:D: **@values is raw, *%_ --> Array:D)
»
```

Comment: "to get all the candidates's signatures" That may work for some methods but it's hit and miss in the general case. Per [the current doc on `lookup`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lookup) it "does not provide a full list of candidates ... if you're after something which can be invoked you probably want to use `find_method` [which] will use a default candidate for parametric roles, whereas `lookup` throws an exception ... and ... [`find_method`] honors `FALLBACK` methods, which `lookup` does not." (And I presume what is true for `find_method` is also true for `find_method_qualified`.)